# Can we add transition animations in Swift Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

Can I add animations in Swift Playground?

[image]

like in the picture. Basically how can I manage to set up by UI in a programme written in Playground?

Answer (score 0):

If the animation takes place in a single view you can use Playground but if you are looking to transition between different views better use a Project which gives you all the tools to handle transitions between views with Storyboard and code based too https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Projects.html